# Github yaml file pulling a file from another branch

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have 2 branches, main and yamltesting. In main I have a test.py file and my yaml file is triggered on push. The yaml file should build an ubuntu linux OS checkout my repo and run a git script to extract the test.py file from "main" branch.

```
name: CI for Hello World
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - yamlTesting
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.11
      - name: Install Libraries
        run: |
          pip install flake8 pytest pytest-cov
      - name: Checkout own repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: "0"
      - name: git
        run: |
          # setup the username and email. I tend to use 'GitHub Actions Bot' with no email by default
          git --version
          git config user.name "Username"
          git config user.email "email@gmail.com"
          git status
          git tag
          git checkout main -- test.py
      - name: list our contents
        run: |
          ls
```

My issue is that when the action runs this error appears

```
error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'test.py' did not match any file(s) known to git
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried the following variations I found.

```
git checkout "main" -- test.py
git checkout main test.py
```

Comment: You have a two-line comment, where the second line isn't commented out, so the shell is trying to run `email` as a command

Comment: Sorry let me edit my qns. It isnt a 2 line comment in my code just 1 long line. Formatting issue @BenjaminW.

Comment: The error message is *exactly* what you get when line 2 starts with `email`.

Comment: Is the workflow file in a public repo, and if so, can you link to it?

Comment: Oh.. sorry I removed the comment and there is the new error


error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git


error: pathspec 'test.py' did not match any file(s) known to git


Here is the repo link: https://github.com/DevOps-Team5-2022/DevOps_Oct2022_Team5_Assignment

Comment: When you check out with the `actions/checkout` action (which, by the way, you should use version 3 of these days), the default behaviour is a shallow clone, getting only the latest commit. In your case, you have already changed that to fetch the entire history. However, this doesn't include other branches; can you try adding a `git fetch origin main` before the `git checkout` command?

Comment: I changed to checkout v3 as you suggested. Using fetch origin main doesn't fix the issue. It still says that main and test.py did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Nvm I solved it. Had to use remotes/origin/main instead of main

Answer (score 0):

Extract file from remote branch needs to use `remotes/origin/<branchName>` instead of just the branch name